# How to count value count by different keys in a hash?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

My hash is:

```
{"20141113"=>[1], "20141114"=>[1, 1]}
```

I want to get:

```
{"20141113"=>[1], "20141114"=>[2]}
```

or

```
{"20141113"=>1, "20141114"=>2}
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get key, sum pair:

```
h.map { |k, v| [k, v.reduce(:+)] }
# => [["20141113", 1], ["20141114", 2]]
```

And convert it to hash using [`Hash::[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D):

```
{"20141113"=>[1], "20141114"=>[1, 1]}
Hash[h.map { |k, v| [k, v.reduce(:+)]}]
# => {"20141113"=>1, "20141114"=>2}
```

Or [`Enumerable#to_h`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_h) (available in Ruby 2.1+)

```
h.map { |k, v| [k, v.reduce(:+)]}.to_h
# => {"20141113"=>1, "20141114"=>2}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
h = {"20141113"=>[1], "20141114"=>[1, 1]}

h.merge(h) { |*_,a| a.reduce(:+) }
  #=> {"20141113"=>1, "20141114"=>2}
```

This uses the form of [Hash#merge](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-merge) that takes a block.